# submit multiple attachment lines to Google DriveApp

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to submit multiple rows of data with an attachment from an input field at the end of each row. I am using a Google App-Script Webapp for this. I am successful in creating an array of objects with the text data (such as date, name, last, etc.), but cannot seem to send the attachment as part of the object. What am I doing wrong?

I should also clarify that this code won't work with either one or multiple attachments.  I would hope that I could send multiple groupings of attachments (hence the array of objects) at one time.

Here is my code on the HTML/Javascript client-side:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("tripPost").addEventListener("click", addLine);
  document.getElementById("submitAll").addEventListener("click", addRecord);
});

//global variables for next functions
var submit = document.getElementById("tripPost");
var submittedTable = document.getElementById("submitted-data");
var mainEntry = document.getElementById("entry-table");
var submitAll = document.getElementById("submitAll");

submittedTable.addEventListener("click", addLine);
submittedTable.addEventListener("change", fileUpload);

function addLine() {
  document.getElementById("table-container").style.display = "block";

  var date = document.getElementById("date1").value;
  var efirst = document.getElementById("efirst").value;
  var elast = document.getElementById("elast").value;

  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var col1 = document.createElement("td");
  col1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(date));
  col1.className = "postDateClass";
  var col2 = document.createElement("td");
  col2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(efirst));
  col2.className = "postEfirstClass";
  var col3 = document.createElement("td");
  col3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(elast));
  col3.className = "postElastClass";

  var col4 = document.createElement("td");

  row.appendChild(col1);
  row.appendChild(col2);
  row.appendChild(col3);
  row.appendChild(col4);

  submittedTable.appendChild(row);

  var uniqueID = "id" + new Date().getTime();
  var upload = document.createElement("input");
  upload.type = "file";
  upload.id = uniqueID;
  upload.name = "myReceipt";
  upload.className = "uploadClass";

  var label = document.createElement("label");
  label.innerHTML = "upload me please!";
  label.htmlFor = uniqueID;
  label.className = "custom-file-upload";

  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.appendChild(upload);
  form.appendChild(label);

  col4.appendChild(form);
}

function fileUpload(e) {
  if (e.target.className === "uploadClass") {
    if (e.target.value) {
      var span = document.createElement("span");
      span.className = "uploadSpanText";
      span.innerHTML = e.target.value.match(/[\/\\]([\w\d\s\.\-\(\)]+)$/)[1];
      e.target.parentElement.appendChild(span);
      e.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "uploaded!";
      e.target.nextElementSibling.style.border = "1px solid #a8e0b4";
      e.target.nextElementSibling.style.color = "#8bca9e";
    }
  }
}

function getFile(file) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = e => {
      const data = e.target.result.split(",");
      const obj = {
        fileName: file.name,
        mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1],
        data: data[1]
      };
      resolve(obj);
    };
    if (file) {
      fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      reject("No File");
    }
  });
}

//gathers inputs and stores values in an object and runs the "addLine" function
async function addRecord(e) {
  var dateLines = document.querySelectorAll(".postDateClass");
  var eFirstLines = document.querySelectorAll(".postEfirstClass");
  var eLastLines = document.querySelectorAll(".postElastClass");
  var attachmentLines = document.querySelectorAll(".uploadClass");
  var mileageData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < dateLines.length; i++) {
    var mileageLines = {};
    mileageLines.travelDate = dateLines[i].textContent;
    mileageLines.firstName = eFirstLines[i].textContent;
    mileageLines.lastName = eLastLines[i].textContent;
    mileageLines.receipt = await getFile(attachmentLines[i].parentNode);

    mileageData.push(mileageLines);
  }

  //send object to google. resets input elements
  google.script.run.userMileageSubmit(mileageData);
}
```

Here is the HTML for the code that I'm working with.

```html
<div id="entry-table">
     <table>
        <h3 style="text-align:left"><u><b>Enter mileage information below.</b></u><br></h3>
        <thead>
         <tr>
              <th >Date</th>
              <th >First:</th>
              <th >Last:</th>
         </tr>
         </thead>

         <tbody id="table-data">
           <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="disabled-results" id="date">
                 <input placeholder="Start Date" id="date1" type="text" class="datekeeper" required>
                <label for="date1" class="active">Date:</label>
              </div>
            <td>
              <div class="disabled-results">
                 <input id ="efirst" type="text" class="validate" >
                 <label for="efirst" class="active">First:</label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="disabled-results">
                 <input id ="elast" type="text" class="validate" >
                 <label for="elast" class="active">Last:</label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div id="status">
                  <button id="tripPost" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small blue darken-3">Add Trip</button>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
</div><!---CLOSE ROW ---> 

<div class="autocomplete" id="table-container" style=display:none>
       <table>
         <thead>
          <tr id="header-titles">
              <th >Date</th>
              <th >First:</th>
              <th >Last:</th>
              <th >Receipt </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <form>
        <tbody class="form" id="submitted-data">
          <div>
              <p>Thank you!</p>
          </div>
          </form>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <br><br>
   </div>

<center>
  <div class="row">    
    <button  id="submitAll" class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-large blue darken-3"><i class="material-icons left">directions_car</i>Submit All Mileage!</button>          
  </div>
</center>
```

Here is the CSS

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    margin-left: 80px;    
    }

    h1{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    }
div.disabled-results{
  width: 175px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-table;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  }

input[type="file"]{
  display: none;
  }

  .custom-file-upload{
    border: 2px solid #000;
    width: 85px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
  }

div.autocomplete{
width: 55px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-table;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

I got everything else to work, except sending the attachment (if any) in each line as part of the object.

I am sure that it can be done. I tried to implement the solution [from this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OU2FAzC04fM) which shows you how to upload a file, but I don't use the `onclick` or `this.parentNode` since I'm not uploading immediately after selecting a file and instead doing a bulk upload when a user has made numerous entries.

Any help in understanding how this should work would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `I should also clarify that this code won't work with either one or multiple attachments. I would hope that I could send multiple groupings of attachments (hence the array of objects) at one time.`. This means `multiple` of input tag? In your case, I think that the file might be required to be retrieved with `FileReader`. But unfortunately, I'm not sure about the detail of your HTML. So in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide HTML? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem but take a read of [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values) if you're trying to send Dates via google.script.run then your going to have problems.  You can send them as a string but not as a Date object.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you. Yes, each line has an input tag for each line. So if a user uses 5 lines, there will be 5 attachments. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: @Cooper Yes, I don't' have an issue with the date formats.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't see the vision of your actually HTML.

Comment: @Tanaike, I've added HTML and javascript code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the sample value of `attachmentLines[i].files[0]`?

Comment: @Tanaike, that's the attachment code. when i console.log this code, I do get the file attachments.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed the modification points as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, yes the `responses.receipt` could cause errors on the Code.gs side. I would need to work on that.  However, the file doesn't even make it to the Code.gs side. It gets stuck in the client-side. I get the message: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed due to illegal value in property: receipt"

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So can you provide the whole script for replicating the error? Of course, please remove your personal information. By this, I would like to confirm the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification? Please think of this as jut one of several possible answers.

Unfortunately, in this case, the file object from HTML side cannot be directly sent to Google Apps Script as a blob. So as one of several workarounds, in this modification, the retrieved files are encoded to the base64 data and send it to Google Apps Script. Then, at Google Apps Script side, the data is decoded and save them as the files.

Please modify your script as follows.

#### HTML and Javascript side:

Please modify `addRecord()` and add `getFile()` as follows.

```
// Added
function getFile(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = e => {
      const data = e.target.result.split(",");
      const obj = {fileName: file.name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
      resolve(obj);
    }
    if (file) {
      fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      reject("No file");
    }
  });
}

async function addRecord(e) { // Modified
  var dateLines = document.querySelectorAll('.postDateClass');
  var attachmentLines = document.querySelectorAll('.uploadClass');

  var mileageData = [];
  for (var i=0; i<dateLines.length; i++){
    var mileageLines = {};
    mileageLines.firstName = document.getElementById("efirst").value; 
    mileageLines.lastName = document.getElementById("elast").value;
    mileageLines.date = dateLines[i].textContent;
    mileageLines.receipt = await getFile(attachmentLines[i].files[0]).catch(e => console.log(e));  // Modified
    mileageData.push(mileageLines); 
  };

  google.script.run.userMileageSubmit(mileageData);
};
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please modify `userMileageSubmit()` as follows.

```
function userMileageSubmit(responses){
  responses.forEach(function(e) {
    var file = e.receipt;
    if (file) {
      var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(file.data), file.mimeType, file.fileName);
      var mainFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('real-drive-link');
      var createFile = mainFolder.createFile(blob);
      var fileUrl = createFile.getUrl();
      Logger.log(fileUrl)
    }
  });

  // row.appendChild(col4)
  // submittedTable.appendChild(row)
}
```

- I cannot understand about `row.appendChild(col4)` and `submittedTable.appendChild(row)`.
- Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your goal at `userMileageSubmit()`. So in this modification, the retrieved files are saved to Google Drive. And the URL of the created file can be seen at the log.

  - Here, please modify this for your actual situation.
- I'm not sure about `real-drive-link`. In this case, please set the folder ID that you want to save the file.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your current `addRecord()` works.
- In this modification, the maximum file size is 50 MB, because the maximum blob size of Google Apps Script is 50 MB. Please be careful this.
- When a lot of files are uploaded, the process time will increase. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)
- [Class Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities)

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. they look promising.  I still get an error saying **TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'**. Any idea what this is about? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @haby22 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Because I cannot understand about the actual value of `attachmentLines[i].files[0]`. So can you provide the sample script for replicating the error? Of course, please remove your personal information. By this, I would like to confirm the issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @haby22 I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. Although I'm not sure about your actual script, I added the error handling to the above script. Please copy and paste the above modified script again and test it. So could you please confirm it? If the file is not created and `No file` can be seen at the console when you use above modified script, `attachmentLines[i].files[0]` might not be the file object. At that time, please check it again.

Comment: Thank you again. I've isolated the code that would help you replicate the error.  Please see the updated code above. Thank you again!

Comment: @haby22 Thank you for replying and updating it. If you tested your updated script, what result did you get? By the way, about your updated script, what is `actualMilesLines` in the function `addRecord`? And when your updated script works, can we think that your initial question was resolved?

Comment: thank you it worked. I fixed the `actualMilesLines`.  Thanks again.

Comment: @haby22 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.